# How to Retrieve data and want to read data from XML  in C#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I am using windows application and I have four combo boxes(comboeventname,combosendtype,comboType,comboschedule) in that form.... I have stored that combo values in to XML file by using XML writer...
Now I want to display the data in that combo boxes in form load event when form opens in run time... How to retrieve that values from that XML file and how to display that data in combo boxes while run time? How shall I do this?

Anyone tell me the solution of this.....

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to load the xml file, pick up the settings for each combo box, and then set the values? If so, could you provide a sample of your xml file?

Comment: "I have stored that combo values in to XML file by using XML writer" - and what exactly does it look like?

Comment: Have you even glanced at the documentation? - I'm not sure its good to ask such basic questions on SO when there are pages and pages of examples that would answer your question in 2 seconds...

Comment: @Adrian - oddly enough, *correctly* using `XmlReader` is *not* what I would call a basic question. Which is why I always advise not to ;-p

Comment: i got four values from that combo boxes and i stored in xML file by save button and xml writer is used to store the values in that XML File....
now i want to display the datas on the combo boxes whenever i run that form from saved XMl file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably much easier to use XmlDocument , or XDocument.

XmlDocument:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectsinglenode.aspx

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //load the xml document;

            XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument;
            xdoc.Load("YourFile.xml");


            // read the values

            // using indexers
            method1 = xdoc["root"]["Element"].Value;

            // using xpath to select nodes
            method2 = xdoc.SelectSingleNode( "root/element/element" ).Value;

            // attributes
            method3 = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("root/element").Attributes["YourAttribute"].Value;

        }
```

XmlReader is better used for large XML files, 1000s of elements, where you don't want to load the whole document into memory. Your document sound far to small to use XmlReader.

Comment: that method2 is indicating what?

Answer (score 2):

We can probably get `XmlReader` working if you show the xml or the code you used to write it, but I'm not sure that is the best option here. Presumably, to display them in a combobox the data-volume isn't immense. In that case, it would be much simpler to use any of:

- XmlDocument
- XDocument
- XmlSerializer

etc to load the data into a DOM or object-model, and work from their. LINQ-to-XML (via `XDocument`) may be particularly appealing. For example, with the xml:

```
<options>
  <option value='123'>ABC</option>
  <option value='234'>DEF</option>
  <option value='567'>GHI</option>
</options>
```

The `XDocument` code like below may work:

```
var options =
      from option in XElement.Parse(xml).Elements("option")
      select new {
         value = (int)option.Attribute("value"),
         text = option.Value
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using an XmlReader. There's a lot of documentation around but here's a start:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9d83k261%28VS.80%29.aspx

Once you have the data you can add them to the your form controls.

Alternatively you could use an XmlDocument - although it does not perform as well as the XmlReader I doubt you will notice with this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I have used before xsd mappings to generate class mappings for an xml document.
On visual studio command prompt line use xsd commands like below .
This will generate mapping class and then 
you should deserialize xml file to object  and cast to generated mapping class.

xsd "path of xml file" this genarates xsd file

than command promt again
xsd "pat of generated xsd file" /CLASSES

for details look at that  [sample](http://sadikdotnet.blogspot.com/search/label/xml%20xsd%20serialize%20deserialize)